# JSF: How to get client browser attributes (height, width) to backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

What's the best way to get client screen attributes to my backing bean? I'd like to work out some dynamic sizing and popup positioning. The application is built with ICEfaces/JSF2.0.

I'm thinking of having a javascript function assigning the client attributes to the value attribute of a hidden input and then grabbing it from there, but I was hoping for something less cumbersome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using JS is the only way to do it, the browser doesn't send these information with a request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727925/dynamically-setting-width-and-heigt-according-to-client-screen-resulotion-in-jfr

Comment: Check out the link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727925/dynamically-setting-width-and-heigt-according-to-client-screen-resulotion-in-jfr

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use filters to determine the screen size and redirect to the specific url to display

Answer (score -1):

I solved this myself by writing a Java Servlet and a JavaScript function that obtains the window size and makes a HTTP request to pass this information to the servlet.  Both the servlet and JSF Managed Beans have access to the HTTP Session ID so I know which web client the HTTP request has come from.

Comment: can you post the code for javascript/xhtml/ and backing bean? Really interested to see how this is done. I've been trying hard myself to figure this out with JSF

Comment: Would be a good idea if you share your code