# Dynamically setting width and height according to client screen resolution in jFreeChart.createBufferedImage(width,Height,info)

Tags: jfreechart

I have a problem regarding JfreeChart.createBufferedImage(width,Height,info)
i am creating a jFreechart in java and showing it in JSF page like this JfreeChart.createBufferedImage(width,Height,info)

Right now i am passing width and height as hardcoded attributes 
but i want the width and height  should dynamically set accoding the cleint screen resolution in JSF page.

Is there any way around to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straight forward way. If you aren't familiar with the JSF lifecycle I would check it out ([balusc made a great article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)), but essentially the process would be this:

1. Initial response is sent to client with javascript
2. Javascript gets screen size and inserts them in hidden fields and submits a form
3. Second response is your current page except with the numbers from the hidden fields.

*You likely will want an ajax enabled framework that will let you poll so that when the window changes your chart can be regenerate appropriately.*

Comment: Link is not available anymore.

Comment: I found a new article and linked to it